# Dynamically adding blocks Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The block are added dynamically to the container `#NotificationList:`

```
var idNotification = $('#NotificationList');
var items = idNotification.find('.item');

$(items).each( function( index, element ){
   console.log(index);
});
```

Problem is that in the cycle is not visible newly added containers `.item`

Comment: P.S. `items` is a jQuery object, so you can just do `items.each(` no need for `$(items)`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but `items` will not be updated when blocks are added or removed from the DOM.  If you updated the page, you're gonna have to do `idNotification.find('.item')` again.

Comment: Use a mutation observer or do the check after you add or remove new items

Comment: Yes, question was resolved.  `items is a jQuery object,`